# java integer to byte, and byte to integer

Tags: java, int, byte

I am aware -that in Java- int is 4 bytes. But I wish to covert an int to n-bytes array, where n can be 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes. I want to have it as signed byte/bytes, so that if I need to convert them back to int (event if it was 1 byte), I get the same signed int. I am fully aware about the possibility of precision loss when converting from int to 3 or lower bytes.

I managed to convert from int to n-byte, but converting it back for a negative number yield unsigned results.

**Edit:**

int to bytes (parameter n specify the number of bytes required 1,2,3, or 4 regardless of possible precession loss)

```
public static byte[] intToBytes(int x, int n) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, x >>>= 8)
        bytes[i] = (byte) (x & 0xFF);
    return bytes;
}
```

bytes to int (regardless of how many bytes 1,2,3, or 4)

```
public static int bytesToInt(byte[] x) {
    int value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        value += ((long) x[i] & 0xffL) << (8 * i);
    return value;
}
```

There is probably a problem in the bytes to int converter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`BigInteger.toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29) will do this for you ...

> Returns a byte array containing the two's-complement representation of this `BigInteger`. The byte array will be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element. **The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this `BigInteger,`** including at least one sign bit, which is `(ceil((this.bitLength() + 1)/8))`. (This representation is compatible with the `(byte[])` constructor.)

Example code:

```
final BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(256);
final byte[] bytes = bi.toByteArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

Prints:

```
[1, 0]
```

To go from the byte array back to a int, use the [`BigInteger(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5b%5d%29) constructor:

```
final int i = new BigInteger(bytes).intValue();
System.out.println(i);
```

which prints the expected:

```
256
```

Comment: I am aware of BigInteger. But BigInteger return exact bytes not 1,2,3, or 4 as instructed. for example 5 will be 1 byte always, but I want the option to have it 2/3/4-bytes.

Comment: I ended up using `new BigInteger(bytes).intValue()` for my `bytesToInt`

Answer (score 6):

Anyway, this is the code I threw together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  final byte[] bi = encode(-1);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bi));
  System.out.println(decode(bi));
}
private static int decode(byte[] bi) {
  return bi[3] & 0xFF | (bi[2] & 0xFF) << 8 |
         (bi[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bi[0] & 0xFF) << 24;
}
private static byte[] encode(int i) {
  return new byte[] { (byte) (i >>> 24), (byte) ((i << 8) >>> 24),
                      (byte) ((i << 16) >>> 24), (byte) ((i << 24) >>> 24)
  };
}
```

Comment: This is for 4 bytes only, and not for 1,2,3, or 4 bytes and back to int as I stated in my question. Also, see what you asked for. Thanks

Comment: So what stops you from picking up the ideas from my code, since it's working? You need to replace your `+` with `|`. Your use of a `long` is uncalled for, btw.

Comment: Mine is working with 4 bytes, btw. Use of long is left there after trial and errors, and I should have removed it before posting. And replacing `+` with `|` changed nothing. The problem is with bytes less than 4 having negative int.

Comment: You need to *sign-extend* the int if it's less than 4 bytes. Or just use `BigInteger` for decoding.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
int unsignedByte = ((int)bytes[i]) & 0xFF;

int n = 0;
n |= unsignedByte << 24;
```